# Determine minimum # of nodes to visit when many nodes can contain same items

Tags: graph-theory

As an example, let's say a food delivery service picks up food at several restaurants to make a single delivery to a customer.  How can I determine minimum # of restaurants to visit when many restaurants can contain same items (e.g. "Soda").

(I suspect that a Dijkstra-like algorithm should be able to solve this, but I can't get my head around how to construct the graph for it.)

Comment: It is called [set cover problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: Thanks. That gives me something to research.  If anyone has any C# code, it would be appreciated.